# Parametrization of varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, parametrization

I know that a variety $X$ that can be parametrized using rational functions is irreducible. My question is:

> What can we get removing or replacing the hypothesis of $X$ being a variety by, for example, $X$ being a quasi-affine(projective) variety?

For example, using the stereographic projection, one can parametrize the $n$-dimensional sphere $S^n$ minus one point. That's a quasi-affine (irreducible) variety, since its the complement of a point in the variety $S^n$.

Is there a general result for these cases?

Comment: What do you mean by the hypothesis of having a variety?

Comment: If $X$ is a variety and $X$ can be parametrized using rational functions, then $X$ is irreducible. I mean, not forcing $X$ to be a variety. I'll rewrite it.

Comment: A variety is irreducible by definition, right? You do not need to assume that it can be parametrized using rational functions.

Comment: @danneks It depends on the context, some books define variety as "irreducible algebraic set" and some others define varieties as algebraic sets. I tried to avoid that ambiguity.

Comment: So you ask whether an algebraic set that can be parametrized is irreducible? Then you may use the easy fact that an image of an irreducible set (an open subset of projective space) is irreducible.

Comment: @danneks no, that's what I know. What I'm asking is if there are similar results when $X$ is, for example, quasi-affine.

Comment: What I said holds for any topological space: an image of an irreducible topological space is irreducible.

Comment: Hello, could you explain or give me a source, why a (rational) parametrizable variety is irreducible?

Comment: @waveman by the time I asked this question I was probably following Cox, Little and O'Shea's *Ideal, Varieties and Algorithms*.